# How to use a struct field into another struct without referring to it as a key

Tags: go, struct

I want to insert a struct field into another struct without having to use the struct name.

**I know that I can do this:**

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
}

type User struct {
  Person
  Email, Password string
}
```

**But It results in this struct:**

```
user := User{Person: Person{Name: ""}, Email: "", Password: ""}
```

**How can I do something like this:**

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
}

type User struct {
  Name Person.Name // Here
  Email, Password string
}
```

**To use it like this**

```
user := User{Name: "", Email: "", Password: ""}
```

**Is it possible?**

Comment: No it's not. Either you embed, or use a named field, or you duplicate the fields.

Comment: You can set in this way \n 
 var u User   \n
 u.Name = "John" \n
 u.Email = "john@test.com" \n
 u.Password = ""  \n without explicitly having to specify u.Person.Name = "John"

Comment: Embedding probably be the easiest to do `type User struct { *Person }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, with the current language implementation you can't.

When initialising a literal you need to be explicit (or, put another way: *literal*! [sic]).  Since a `User` contains a `Person`, a literal `User` must contain a literal `Person`, as you illustrate:

```golang
    u := User{ 
        Person: Person{
            Name: "Bob",
        },
        Email: "bob@bobspot.com",
        Password: "you're kidding right?",
    }
```

However, once you have a *variable* of type `User`, you can then leverage the anonymous field to set (or get) the `Name` of the anonymous `Person` with the `User`:

```golang
    u := User{}
    u.Name = "Bob"
    u.Email = "bob@bobspot.com",
    u.Password = "you're kidding right?",
```

### Why Does Go Make Me Do All This Work?

Let us imagine that it was possible to initialise the inner `Person` in the way you are looking for:

```golang
    u := User{ Name: "Bob" }
```

Now let us further imagine that we later modify the `User` struct and *add* its own `Name` field:

```golang
    type User struct {
        Person
        Name string
        Email string
        Password string
    }
```

And now you *can* obviously initialise the new `Name` field:

```golang
    u := User{ Name: "Bob" }
```

Notice that this is identical to the previous code that initialised `User.Person.Name` but now it is initialising `User.Name`.  Not good.

### More Gotchas

There are further traps lurking with code like this.

First, the addition of a `Name` field in `User` *already* similarly "breaks" unqualified references to `Name` on `User` variables:

```golang
    u.Name = "Bob" // used to set User.Person.Name, now sets User.Name
```

Also, with only an anonymous `Person` field, the `User.Person.Name` field is marshalled to JSON by default as a "Name" field:

```json
    {
        "Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Password": ""
    }
```

If a `Name` field is added, then *this* is the field that is marshalled as `"Name"` and the `User.Person.Name` field is not marshalled *at all*.

You might think you can add a `json` tag for the `User.Person.Name`, e.g.

```golang
    type User struct {
        Person   `json:"PersonName"`
        Name     string
        Email    string
        Password string
    }
```

But *now* the `Person` is marshalled as an *object* with a `Name` field:

```json
    {
        "PersonName": {
            "Name": ""
        },
        "Name": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Password": ""
    }
```

*This also happens if you try to change the marshalled field name of the anonymous `Person` even if `User` does not have a `Name` field*.

In short: using anonymous *structs within structs* as a way of "adding fields" is potentially problematic and fragile and should probably be avoided.